# How can I hide 1 pager website's slug for each section?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I made a 1 pager website that has a pagination for each section like if you press the first page it will just scroll to top most while pressing the last page will bring you to the bottom most section. The url will become `websitename.com/#1stpage`, `websitename.com/#2ndpage`, etc.
How can I hide the `#pagename` in the url?
btw I am using wordpress maybe you guys can point out if there is something in the settings I didn't know exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Appearance -> Menus -> remove page name in Custom Links URL in right side (http://www.example.com/#pagename) -> Save Menu

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome! Happy to Help you :)